# D3 graph is missing as much text elements as there are ticks in axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I experience the weirdest problem:

- If I draw my axis **before** my graph, the graph misses as much text elements as there are ticks in the axis. When I increase or decrease the number of ticks, the number of missing text elements increases or decreases alike.

[image: Axis drawn before graph]

- If I draw my axis **after** my graph, everything is alright.

[image]

- I want to draw the axis first, as I want the grid lines to appear below the graph. *And first of all, I want to understand what is going on here.*

Here the code snippet in question:

```
var generateVisualization = function() {
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 10};
var width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = (dataset.length * 11) + 5;

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([1850, 2020])
    .range([0, width])

var xAxisBottom = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("d")); // removes the comma as thousands separator

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

// Axis drawn first
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxisBottom); 

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(d.BeginDate);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 11 + 3;
    })
    .attr("width", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(d.EndDate) - xScale(d.BeginDate);
    })
    .attr("height", 4)
    .attr("class", "line");

svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.DisplayName;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(d.BeginDate) + (xScale(d.EndDate) - xScale(d.BeginDate)) + 4;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 11 + 8;
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", 8);

// Alternative: Axis drawn last 
/*
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxisBottom); 
*/
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch:

Instead of this:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.DisplayName;
    })
```

do this:

```
svg.selectAll(".myLabel")//selection via class
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "myLabel")//adding a class to the label
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.DisplayName;
    })
```

**Reason**: when you do

`svg.selectAll("text")`

It will select the text on ticks, and bind the data to it. This is the reason for the anomaly... you increase the ticks the labels displayed decreases.

The above solution will add the class `myLabel` to only the labels but not the tick text, so the problem should resolve.

Comment: Thank you especially for the explanation of the reason behind it!